# How to handle Enums as string in spring data jpa Specification

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, spring-data-jpa

Trying to use [specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) for filter data at database level.
I have an entity with another entity as an instance wherein the instance variable class contains an Emun field.
This defaults to a string in the database for the enum field.

```
@Entity
public class Outer{

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "current_status")
    private Status current;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "past_status")
    private Status past;
...
...

@Entity
public class Status{

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "state")
    private State state;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid",strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "outer_id")
    private Outer outer;
```

I have created `static meta models` for both the classes.

How do I create a `Predicate` to match `State` using a `where in` clause with the enum values supplied as `Strings`(not instances of enums) ?

Comment: Well passing in a set of `Enum` i.e.- `State` does it for me in the `in` clause with the obvious fact that i need to convert `Strings` to `Enums`.

Comment: In the first place, can you nest entities? As per JPA spec they must be top-level classes.

Comment: Sorry @ujulu if my statements are misleading. But the Entities are not nested, i.e. -  not an inner class. Note that both the classes are `public`. Its only that I have not showed the complete class.

Comment: From your question it is not clear why you could not use Enum values instead of Strings. If you post the `State` and the list of `Strings` it might be clear for us.

Comment: `final Predicate statusPredicate = cb.or(root.join(Outer_.current).get(Status_.state).in(states),root.join(Outer_.past).get(Status_.state).in(states));` - This solves it for me.

Answer (score 3):

You modeled the entity attribute as an `Enum` and Hibernate, therefore, expects an enum in all JPQL or Criteria queries.

So, you either have to map all `String`s to `State` enums or use a [native SQL query](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/).

Hibernate doesn't parse native queries, and they are based on the table model instead of the entity model. That allows you to use the `String` representation of your `State` enum.
You can do something like this:

```
List<State> states = ... // get or initialize your State list here
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Status s WHERE state IN (:states)", Status.class);
q.setParameter("states", states);
List<Status> s = (List<Status>) q.getResultList();
```

The second parameter of the `createNativeQuery` method tells Hibernate to map each record of the result set to a `Status` entity. These entities are managed, and you can use them to update or remove the mapped database records.

To use this mapping, you need to make sure that your query selects all columns mapped by the entity. I wrote a series of posts that get into more details on the different result mapping options:

- [Result Set Mapping: The Basics](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/)
- [Result Set Mapping: Complex Mappings](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2015/04/result-set-mapping-complex.html)
- [Result Set Mapping: Constructor Result Mappings](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-constructor-result-mappings/)
- [Result Set Mapping: Hibernate specific features](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-hibernate-specific-mappings/)

Comment: Thanks @Thorben but as I had updated in my 1st comment, I already have it answered. I am passing instances of the enum in the `in` field after creating a join on the instance class.